# Counting jump(no of lines) between first two 'String' occurrences in a file

Tags: python, string, readline, readfile

I have a huge data file with a specific string being repeated after a defined number of lines.

counting jump between first two 'Rank' occurrences. For example the file looks like this:

```
  1 5 6 8 Rank                     line-start
  2 4 8 5
  7 5 8 6
  5 4 6 4
  1 5 7 4 Rank                     line-end  
  4 8 6 4
  2 4 8 5
  3 6 8 9
  5 4 6 4 Rank
```

You can notice that the string Rank is repeated every 3rd line. So the number of lines in a block is 4 for the above example. My Question is how do i get the number of lines using python readline().

I currently follow this:

```
data = open(filename).readlines()
count = 0
for j in range(len(data)):
  if(data[j].find('Rank') != -1): 
    if count == 0: line1 = j
    count = count +1 
  if(count == 2):
    no_of_lines = j - line1
    break
```

Any improvements or suggestions welcome.

Comment: you want to count total lines in the file, or only the lines with the word rank in them?

Comment: @InbarRose want to count the no.of lines in-between the lines which contain the string Rank.

Comment: if the lines is same for each block, just count 1st block.

Comment: Thank you @fanlix Yes, That's what i exactly need. You can notice the break statement in my code which stops the loop after finding the no.of lines in the 1st block

Comment: i cant finish this job in less than 5 lines of codes. waiting for some pro....

Comment: @fanlix Can you please post your code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to find the number of lines in a block where each block starts with a line that contains 'Rank' e.g., there are 3 blocks in your sample: 1st has 4 lines, 2nd has 4 lines, 3rd has 1 line:

```
from itertools import groupby

def block_start(line, start=[None]):
    if 'Rank' in line:
       start[0] = not start[0]
    return start[0]

with open(filename) as file:
     block_sizes = [sum(1 for line in block) # find number of lines in a block
                    for _, block in groupby(file, key=block_start)] # group
print(block_sizes)
# -> [4, 4, 1]
```

If all blocks have the same number of lines or you just want to find number of lines in the first block that starts with `'Rank'`:

```
count = None
with open(filename) as file:
     for line in file:
         if 'Rank' in line:
             if count is None: # found the start of the 1st block
                count = 1
             else: # found the start of the 2nd block
                break
         elif count is not None: # inside the 1st block
             count += 1
print(count) # -> 4
```

Comment: Sorry for the misleadng example, all the blocks have same number of lines, I have not completely typed it. Finding the no.of lines in the first block itself is enough

Comment: Is it similar to my code logic, except using readlines. I used readlines because I have some post processing of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `.readlines()` when a simple generator expression counting the lines with `Rank` is enough:

```
count = sum(1 for l in open(filename) if 'Rank' not in l)
```

`'Rank' not in l` is enough to test if the string `'Rank'` is not present in a string. Looping over the open file is looping over all the lines. The `sum()` function will add up all the `1`s, which are generated for each line not containing `Rank`, giving you a count of lines without `Rank` in them.

If you need to count the lines from `Rank` to `Rank`, you need a little `itertools.takewhile` magic:

```
import itertools
with open(filename) as f:
    # skip until we reach `Rank`:
    itertools.takewhile(lambda l: 'Rank' not in l, f)
    # takewhile will have read a line with `Rank` now
    # count the lines *without* `Rank` between them
    count = sum(1 for l in itertools.takewhile(lambda l: 'Rank' not in l, f)
    count += 1  # we skipped at least one `Rank` line.
```

Comment: I want to count the lines in between the lines which has Rank

Comment: @Alaissham: simple 'not' added then. :-)

Comment: The problem is, I want to include the line which has the string 'Rank' and count the subsequent lines until the line reaches and finds a line with the string Rank(this line not included).

Answer (score 2):

counting jump between first two `'Rank'` occurrences:

```
def find_jumps(filename):
    first = True
    count = 0
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'Rank' in line:
                if first:
                    count = 0 
                    #set this to 1 if you want to include one of the 'Rank' lines.
                    first = False                    
                else:
                    return count
            else:
                count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

7 line of codes:

```
count = 0
for line in open("yourfile.txt"):
    if "Rank" in line: 
        count += 1
        if count > 1: break 
    elif count > 0: count += 1
print count
```

Comment: Sorry again for the misleading example, I have some more irrelevant lines in the starting and end of the file.